# Electron ShareMenu Example

Tags: electron

Electron has an [API for the macOS share menu](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/api/share-menu), but the page does not include an example of how to use it. I'm struggling to get started, as I'm not sure which file to put the code in, or how to plumb it to an interface element. How do you use the ShareMenu API?

Answer (score 0):

This is a year old, so you may have already figured it out, but for anyone who's confused I hope this helps.

Assuming you're familiar with electron's IPC system (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc), here's an example workflow that might work for you.

1. User right-clicks on an image.
2. Renderer process (Browser Window) sends IPC message to main process with URL to open.
3. Main process listening for said message receives it and takes the URL and possibly downloads it to local disk.
4. This pseudocode should explain it.

```
if( downloadedFile ) {
  const shareMenu = new ShareMenu( { filePaths: [pathToFileOnDisk] } );
  shareMenu.popup();
} else {
  const shareMenu = new ShareMenu( { urls: [urlFromBrowser] } );
  shareMenu.popup();
}
```

After that, a contextual menu will open in the active browser window [an alternative is to specify the target window in the call to shareMenu.popup() as shown in docs].

When an app is selected, the URL or the downloaded file will be sent to the targeted app to be shared and the menu will be closed.

This is the basic answer.  If you get this working, try out some of the options from the API docs for [ShareMenu](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/share-menu).  Another page from the docs, that for whatever reason isn't linked to on that page is the constructer parameters for new ShareMenu([sharingItem](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/structures/sharing-item))

I think the most difficult part would be to set things up for handling the IPC.  This code needs to be run in the main process, but the menu needs to display in the window.  IPC is the key.